# PyCharm "Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): lchown /Dockerfile: invalid argument"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I'm trying to create a remote interpreter in PyCharm 2021.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. While running
**Add Interpreter -> Docker** and selecting: **Server: Docker-rootless, Image name: python:3.7-slim-buster**, and **Interpreter path: python**, I get this error:

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): lchown /Dockerfile: invalid argument
```

Other info:

1. I have recently removed some old containers and images. I have also updated PyCharm. Before that, remote interpreters used to work.
2. `docker-compose up` works fine when used from the CLI.

What I've tried:

1. Changing the assigned user id ranges in /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid
2. Removing PyCharm cache (except local history)
3. Reinstalling PyCharm
4. Googling the error verbatim and in variations, to no avail

If anyone has any idea of what this might be, I'd be grateful :)